# SQL Server Profiler shows a StartTime greater than EndTime

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I'm using *SQL Server Profiler* to check some long run query. Somehow I see some entries in SQL Server profiler show `StartTime` is greater than the `EndTime`, and the Duration value is obviously overflow.

Why is this happening? Any advice? Thanks in advance.

[image: SQL Profiler ScreenShot]

[image: Some Examples]

Comment: On my machine I don't see error during that time, and I don't have access to logon the server so I'm not able to tell if there is error on server side.

Comment: I'm running the Profiler on my local machine against the SQL Server hosted on another machine. Thanks a lot for the information about Extended Events, I'm looking into it.

Comment: What eventclass are these? There is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846829/sql-server-profiler-strange-duration-starttime-is-greater-than-endtime) question posted but no answer. But if it is related to timeout [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80165/tracking-down-application-timeout-errors-in-sql-server) might help.